Definition of a Random Set without measure theory
I've been looking for a non-measure theoretic definition of a random set (both discrete and continuous case), and it's surprisingly hard to find.
Resources I have looked at:

This math.stackexchange answer: Definition of Random Set
A popular book on random sets is locked behind a paywall.

Does anyone have a simple definition of it? I'm looking to understand it in the context of confidence sets for statistical inference.

Why do you want to avoid measure theory ? Maybe a first question you want to answer before that is:
How would you define a real random variable without measure theory ?

FWIW, a good chunk of the (free) appendix to the book you linked is dedicated to measure theory, so the book almost certainly assumes background in measure-theoretic probability.

@P.Quinton I don't come from a math background (CompSci major). I find measure theory obtuse for most probability work I tend to do.

@P.Quinton I would define a r.v. $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a mapping function which, on execution of the random experiment, crystallizes into a real value from its range. This is further subdivided into cases where its domain is continuous or discrete. I'm looking for a definition of a random set which is in a similar vein.

@AbhishekDivekar I also come from a CS background, measure theory takes a bit of effort to get into but it provides all the tools that your need and it is not too hard in the end. Probabilities and random things are a nightmare to define without those unless the domain is finite. My best bet is that, as of today, you cannot define a random set without Measure Theory.
